# what are valid zone name or valid service name for srv records?

Tags: domain-name-system, srv-record

I've been following a few guides/questions on how to use A records and SRV records to map a domain to a specific ip and port like `1.1.1.1:1889`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433570/how-to-use-srv-or-any-other-record-do-redirect-a-domain

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015138/how-to-redirect-dns-to-different-ports

In questions like the ones above, they recommend using SRV records.  The only part I'm not clear on is how to determine the correct `service` name to use in my SRV record?  For example, let's say I have these records

```
mysql.example.com.  86400 IN A 1.1.1.1
mongo.example.com.  86400 IN A 1.1.1.1
www.example.com.  86400 IN A 1.1.1.1
mosquitto.example.com.  86400 IN A 1.1.1.1
_mysql._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 20 3306 mysql.example.com.
_mongo._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 20 27017 mongo.example.com.
_http._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 20 3306 www.example.com.
_mqtt._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 20 3306 mosquitto.example.com.
```

**Are the `_mysql, _mongo, _http and _mqtt` the correct service names to use in my SRV records?**  I completely guessed these service names because I wasn't able to find a website that lists all the acceptable service names that can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First web browsers do not follow `SRV` records at all, so even if you can design them, they are useless.

Now given the generic process to know what goes into any record, taking `SRV` as an example.

IANA is the guardian of things so go to https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#dns-parameters-4 where you can see for `SRV` that it is defined in RFC 2782

There it is defined as such:

> Here is the format of the SRV RR, whose DNS type code is 33:
>
> ```
>    _Service._Proto.Name TTL Class SRV Priority Weight Port Target
> ```

with then respectively:

> Service
>
> ```
>    The symbolic name of the desired service, as defined in Assigned
>    Numbers [STD 2] or locally.  An underscore (_) is prepended to
>    the service identifier to avoid collisions with DNS labels that
>    occur in nature.
> ```

and

> Proto
>
> ```
>    The symbolic name of the desired protocol, with an underscore
>    (_) prepended to prevent collisions with DNS labels that occur
>    in nature.  _TCP and _UDP are at present the most useful values
>    for this field, though any name defined by Assigned Numbers or
>    locally may be used (as for Service).  The Proto is case
>    insensitive.
> ```

[STD 2] reference is RFC 1700 but RFC 3232 obsoleted it to make a database online of possible values... which is again administered by IANA.

It is now there: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml and do note that it is basically what you find in file `/etc/services` in any Unix box.

So taking back your examples (your port numbers are wrong in multiple `SRV` records depicted though):

- `mysql` is indeed defined for port `3306` so it is valid as service name and hence in an `SRV` record
- for port `27017`, the service name is `mongodb`, not `mongo` (but do Mongo clients honor `SRV` records?)
- `http` is indeed defined for port `80` so it is a valid service name (and `https` for port 443)
- `mqtt` is defined as valid port name, for port `1883`. But same question as above, do clients use `SRV` records at all?

Do note also that there are in the wild various `SRV` records not following the above. If they can be published they "work", that is nothing will prevent resolution of them at the DNS level even if they don't use a registered service name as above, as long as some application of course do read them.

For example, you can find lots of example with `_sip._tls` or `_sipfederationtls._tcp` online, which are both wrong: `tls` is not a valid protocol, and `sipfederantiontls` is not a valid service name (and is in fact too long, as https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335.html#section-5.1 specifies it should be at most 15 characters long). So some tool/UI may prevent creating those records in a zonefile, and some nameservers may refuse to load them, but in most cases they will work (if applications do consume them).

Comment: "if applications do consume them": does that mean that the application will actually read the `_minecraft._tcp` value in the SRV field, and only then actually consume it? I was under the impression that as long as the target and port matched, it would work. Can I make up any name for my record, or must I make sure I use the one the client expects?

Comment: If the application does not request resolution of the `SRV` name, then it can't obviously use the results. As for how the `SRV` record is built, no you can not just imagine things, they follow specific patterns... even if, obviously, actors like MS just decided to invent their own. But still it all depends what the client does, if it does `SRV` at all, and if it does, what it expects as service and protocol.

Comment: From my understanding, then, the application will ask the DNS server «hey, do you have a SRV record for `_myservice._tcp`?», to which the DNS server may answer with a record, or just say «nope, ain't got it». It's not some metadata which gets shipped with the `A`/`AAAA` record, as an addendum.

Comment: Yes, that is how ALL DNS requests work. There is no concept of metadata and attaching one thing to another. A request is one name, one record type sent to one nameserver. A response is either an error, or the data attached for the name and record type.